# Weird behaviour of httpcomponents

Tags: java, cookies, httpclient, apache-httpcomponents

I know that httpcomponents it's not a browser but I'm just using it to retrieve some cookies from a web server. The problem is that when I send an HTTP request I don't get the same set of cookies as when I navigate using Firefox. The site is www.amazon.com. I thought that it would be easy but I don't see which is the problem. Here is my code:

```
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://www.amazon.com");

    System.out.println("Initial set of cookies:");
    List<Cookie> cookies = httpclient.getCookieStore().getCookies();
    if (cookies.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("None");
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("- " + cookies.get(i).toString());
        }
    }

    HttpResponse response = null;
    try {
        response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

    System.out.println("Post logon cookies:");
    cookies = httpclient.getCookieStore().getCookies();
    if (cookies.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("None");
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("- " + cookies.get(i).toString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Amazon might not allow you to do stuff like that (carefully read their T&Cs). From a technical perspective you might need to 'behave like a browser', check the HTTP request headers Firefox sends to the server and dump those...

Comment: I've checked the HTTP Header with the `Live HTTP Headers` Add-on for Firefox. It is really weird because it seems that HTTPComponents gets stuck in the first redirection and it has FOLLOW_REDIRECTS activated by default...

Comment: How does someonte know the redirect url from the header response? (the response code is 200 not 3x!)

Comment: if you want to know final redirect url see  http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html#d5e200